# Content show with animation of individual row of listview android

Tags: android, listview

Android: I want  to show pause and leave  button(show in  atteched image) when swip right to left on individual row and hide when swip left to right.[image]

Comment: Have you tried googling? When I was looking for a way to do this, I found hundreds of results on how to do this online. Great libraries.

Comment: The image is too large.

Comment: hi alex which library use for this ?

Comment: alex please tell me which library use for it